# Handle gradle tasks dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Using gradle with its spring-boot plugin (1.5.1) and a [first spirit plugin](https://github.com/moritzzimmer/gradle-fsm) together raises an error:

```
D:\Coden\WS\STS\fs-db-import>gradle build                                                     
:genJaxb                                                                                      
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                                       
:processResources UP-TO-DATE                                                                  
:classes UP-TO-DATE                                                                           
:jar UP-TO-DATE                                                                               
:fsm UP-TO-DATE                                                                               
:bootRepackage FAILED                                                                         

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                      

* What went wrong:                                                                            
Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.                                                   
> Unable to deduce layout for 'D:\Coden\WS\STS\fs-db-import\build\fsm\fs-db-import-0.0.1.fsm'
```

It seems that bootRepackage from the spring boot plugin can't handle or package the fsm file.

**a)** how can I exclude it?

Another approach would be to switch the 'fsm' and the 'bootRepackage' task, but adding the following lines to build.gradle

```
bootRepackage.dependsOn -= fsm
tasks.bootRepackage.dependsOn -= fsm
fsm.dependsOn bootRepackage
```

results in

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:bootRepackage
\--- :fsm
     \--- :bootRepackage (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

**b)** how do I remove 'fsm'`s dependency from 'bootRepackage'?

**c)** is it possible to show a gradle task dependency graph? (not project dependencies)

Answer (score 3):

By default the Spring Boot plugin attempts to repackage all tasks of type `Jar`. Sine the FSM task extends from `Jar` the plugin attempts to repackage them both. You can explicitly tell the plugin which `Jar` task to use.

```
bootRepackage {
    withJarTask jar
}
```

More information can be found in the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration).

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I used your suggestion.